# Combining multiple rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I want to select both the rows 489-493 and the rows 503-504 in this dataframe.  I can slice them separately by df.iloc[489:493] and df.iloc[503:504], respectively, but am not sure how to combine them?

[image]

I have  tried using  df[(df.State =='Washington') & (df.State=='Wisconsin')] , however, I'm getting an empty dataframe with the column labels only. 
if I do only one of them, eg. df[df.State =='Washigton'] this works fine, to produce 5 rows with Washington as expected.
So how can I combine them?

Comment: What's your expected output

Comment: ```df[(df.State =='Washington') |(df.State=='Wisconsin')]```? It should be ```or``` not ```and```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `df[df.State.isin(('Washington', 'Wisconsin'))]`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], at the very least share your data in a more convenient format. Images are not great for this kind of information, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

use pandas.DataFrame.loc.

```
df = df.loc[['Washington','Wisconsin'],['Region Name']]
```

Comment: your code has thrown an error,  KeyError: KeyError("None of [Index(['Washington', 'Wisconsin'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]",)

Comment: Omit the region name

Comment: Please show your current codes as well, it would be easier for others to help to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

df.iloc[np.r_[489:493, 503:504], :] worked for me!